# Dynamics crm 2011 user load testing

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am a Dynamics CRM 2011 sys admin for a community charity providing in home healthcare and support to individuals referred to us by our local District Health Board. We are currently at the testing stage of a project to develop and implement a CRM patient management system and would like to test the configuration to see if it can handle the 200 District Nurse and Support Worker staff who will need to use the system when we go live.

What I need to know is if anyone has had experience in user load stress testing for an on-premise Dynamics CRM 2011 system before and what the best approach might be for us to take to do this. We don't have a lot of money to spend on an off the shelf product (if there is one) or developing our own user load testing application. I have searched all the forum's and other CRM sites but I can't find anything to suggest what out best approach to solving the problem is or if we actually need to perform user stress testing with the configuration we have.

Our application server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 with 6GB of RAM, 80GB System Drive, 40GB Data Drive, 20GB Log Drive and 2 x 2.50 GHz CPU.

Our SQL Server is running Windows Server 2012 R2 and SQL Server 2012 with 32GB of RAM, 80GB System Drive, 150GB Data Drive, 50GB Log Drive and 2 x 2.50 GHz CPU.

All users login via an Active Directory account

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested the Perf tool kit is worth looking at to simulate the required load. With the kit you have you should be ok but it depends  on many factors. How and where will they be connection to the system and on what device - system itself maybe ok but there's always the risk that the network could cause issues - check this put along with other resources on this site : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/04/09/using-the-crm-diagnostics-page-to-capture-network-performance.aspx

Comment: Thanks Del, I hadn't heard about the diagnostic tool and that is exactly what I needed to test the latency for our DN staff accessing CRM from out in the field which is the area I was worried about the most.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a free product that allows you to stress test a Dynamics CRM system with a number of fake users. It takes a bit of setting up but does what you want it to

http://pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-gb/applications/performance-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-12884915630

Comment: Thanks for the info Kevin, I'd already downloaded the toolkit and just waiting on approval to install it. I didn't read anything in the documentation about user stress testing though.